# Visual Studio 2008 run-time stack overflow warning when operator< recursive on all paths

Tags: c++, visual-c++, gcc4.7

The C++ code below generates the following warning in Visual Studio 2008:

> 1>c:...\sample.cpp(6) : warning C4717: 'operator<' : recursive on all control paths, function will > cause runtime stack overflow

If I use the Sample class on any situation that the needs operator<, it actually crashes with a stack overflow error (for example after inserting the second Sample object in a multiset). The constructor keeps being called until it runs out of stack space.

The code below is all that's needed to generate the warning on its own (without anything in the code referencing the Sample class).

```
// Sample.hpp
#include <iostream>

class __declspec(dllexport) Sample
{
  std::string ID;
public:
  Sample (std::string id):ID(id) {};
  friend bool __declspec(dllexport) operator<(const Sample& s1, const Sample& s2);
};


// Sample.cpp
#include "Sample.hpp"

bool operator<(const Sample& s1, const Sample& s2)
{
  return s1.ID<s2.ID;
}
```

The warning shows with VC++ and VS2008 (Win32, /W3) on Win7. For the same platform and exactly the same code, but with MinGW GCC 4.7.3 on eclipse, I don't get any warning.

If I add the < string > header the warning disappears in VS2008 and any use of the Sample class works perfectly fine.

Also, if I declare the Sample constructor explicit, VS2008 throws the following compile error:

> 1>.\Sample.cpp(5) : error C2678: binary '<' : no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of > type 'const std::string' (or there is no acceptable conversion)
>   1>        c:...\Sample.hpp(13): could be 'bool operator <(const Sample &,const Sample &)'
>   1>        while trying to match the argument list '(const std::string, const std::string)'

However, setting the constructor explicit in GCC still doesn't generate any warnings nor errors (I set the warnings in Eclipse to the most comprehensive levels I could).

I'd like to know if someone can please roughly explain how VS2008 determines when to generate this stack overflow warning. In this case, it turns out to be correct so I'm curious to see how it's done. Also, if possible, why GCC behaves differently here please. Hopefully this makes sense.

Comment: You definitely need to include `<string>` to be able to compare `std::string` objects. Not sure if that solves ALL of the problems, but it should solve the second one.

Comment: From the error messages, it's clear that VC++ is implementing the comparison by constructing a `Sample` object from each string you're comparing, then comparing them. That's why the explicit ctor breaks it, and why it's infinitely recursive -- because it constructs ew temporary objects of the same type as it received as parameters, and tries to compare them.

Comment: @Mats Thanks. I've got a fair amount of legacy code to look after. When I added that class to a set container I got a stack overflow error. At least it was a clear obvious crash and not a nasty leak bug. Somehow the coder forgot to include < string >, probably because it'd still compile fine. It didn't help either that about a dozen warnings were manually disabled in the project file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because at the point of comparison `std::string` is an incomplete type and the conversion constructor `Sample (std::string id)` is being *implicitly* invoked. In the expression `s1.ID<s2.ID` both the LHS and RHS are being implicitly converted to a temporary `Sample` and the conversion operator then gets called again (and again and again).

You need to include `<string>` so the complete definition of `std::string` is visible *and* I highly recommend declaring the constructor of sample `explicit`.

Comment: Understood, makes sense thanks. Still wonder how it happened vc++ detected and warned about the impending stack overflow whereas gcc didn't. From your explanation it seems the fact that the conversion operator gets called again and again is not implementation dependent.

Comment: The compiler is not required to issue a warning about the recursion. Check the GCC compile options and up the warning levels with `-Wall -Wextra -Wstrict-aliasing -Wstrict-overflow` to see if it catches the overflow. You are correct that the conversion is not implementation dependent and is well defined by the standard (Start with 4.2 [conv]). As a side note, if the comparison operator was a member of `Sample` the implicit conversion would not happen.